# I need to find the total salary which is the sum of commission and salary (JS)

Tags: javascript, object

Given the array:

```js
let Employee = [{
  id: 1123,
  department: "Sales",
  ['basic salary']: 10000,
  commission: 3000,
}, {
  id: 1223,
  department: "HR",
  ['basic salary']: 9100,
  commission: 1,
}, {
  id: 1323,
  department: "IT",
  ['basic salary']: 12000,
  commission: 33000,
}, {
  id: 1423,
  department: "Support",
  ['basic salary']: 10000,
  commission: 1000,
}, {
  id: 1523,
  department: "HR",
  ['basic salary']: 910000,
  commission: 2300,
}, {
  id: 1123,
  department: "Sales",
  ['basic salary']: 91000,
  commission: 2300,
}];
```

So my question is, how can I calculate the total for each department, if the total = the sum of salary and commission?

Comment: If you create `const totals = {};` first you can then simply iterate over the array and add to `total[item.department]` if it exists, or set it to the sum if it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: What have you tried yourself. Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

```
const moneyForDepartment = {};

Employee.forEach((emp) => {
   if (moneyForDepartment[emp.department] === undefined) {
      moneyForDepartment[emp.department] = 0;
   }
   moneyForDepartment[emp.department] += emp.commission + emp["basic salary"];
})

console.log(moneyForDepartment);
```

you just need to loop and build an object with key that represent total amount of each department